# In Ext JS, how to get the id or other info of the node which is dragged and dropped in tree structure?

Tags: extjs, drag-and-drop, tree

I have created a dragable tree structure using Ext JS.
I want the id of the node being dragged in 'drop' function of tree panel listener so that I can pass it to one php file for processing.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you are listening to the drop event, you are passed the DOM node and data from the dropped item:

http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.tree.plugin.TreeViewDragDrop-event-drop

e.g.

```
    this.mon(this, 'drop', this._onDrop, this);

    _onDrop: function(rowEl, dropData, overModel, dropPosition, opts) {
        var droppedRecord = dropData.records[0];
    },
```

then the droppedRecord should have the ID you need.